# What is the shell interpretor path on iSeries?

Tags: shell, ibm-midrange

On linux systems, it is good practice to prefix shell scripts by a commentary giving the path to the requiered shell to execute.

example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#or
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

This makes the shell syntax awaited explicit (and it is a final touch telling people the script has been reviewed).

But I'm currently writing scripts on iSeries (AS400) where I use `qsh`.
And I don't know if there is something similar to write on top of my scripts.

Do you know the path to the interpretor? What do you write in your scripts?

Comment: echo $path   I can't really make this an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
#!/bin/qsh
```

In PASE (call qp2term) you can use

```
#!/bin/sh
```